# skip CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX if empty

Tags: c, cmake, cpack

As a part of a big C project compiled with cmake, I added a new utility component `util` which is installed (with cpack) to a `util` rpm and debian package.
the project [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) is set to `/a`

```
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/a" )
```

and `util` content is installed in another path `/b`

```
install (TARGETS util_target COMPONENT util DESTINATION /b )
```

Since `util` is generated in the same cmake process, the generated package contains the empty directory `/a`. I would like to remove it, so the generated package will contain only the files in `/b`.
Using some post installation script is not a solution for this issue, since the .deb/.rpm files will include the redundant directory `/a`.

Comment: So your question effectively narrows down to "How do I specify different prefix paths for different install components"? Is there some common prefix other than `/`? how would your install command look for the normal component? `install(TARGETS standard_target RUNTIME)`?

Comment: @fabian correct. regarding the last question - the line example you wrote will be installed under CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  (`/a`).